# Ubuntu settings really slow

Tags: performance, system

I have a Compaq 6910p Laptop and Ubuntu used to work like a charm. Couple weeks ago I installed it fresh (16.04 LTS) and suddenly the boot takes quiet a long time and so do the settings. I installed 17.04 now but that didn't fix the problem. 
When I log in and hit Systems settings it takes about 20 to 30 seconds for them to appear, changing the wallpaper crashes the system. The whole system seems really slow. Programs like chrome, LibreOffice etc are not affected, open fast and work smoothly.

I run dmesg and found this line in-between a few times, always with a 10 second delay:

```
[drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] ERROR [CRTC:29:pipe A] flip_done timed out
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu release you had before, the one that "worked like a charm"?

Comment: Also 16.04, so might have been an update or something like that. I run dmesg and found that line inbetween a few times, always with a 10 second delay

**[drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper]] *ERROR* [CRTC:29:pipe A] flip_done timed out**

Comment: A kernel update, definitely. The same error has been reported in PCs with certain Intel Graphics and kernel 4.8.x. across multiple distros including Fedora and ArchLinux.

Comment: I may suggest a workaround but have to ask you first: Do you use the S-Video port? Reason: The "fix" disables the S-Video port.

Comment: I have no screens connected if that is your question

Comment: Great. Tentative answer coming soon...

Comment: I'm willing to try any fix. Worst thing that can happen I install fresh, no problem. Its not my main PC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message suggests a bug that has been making the rounds for some time now, affecting some PCs with Intel Graphics running kernel 4.8.x and newer.

I should be corrected anytime soon. Meanwhile you can try the following workaround. Please note this parameter will **disable the S-Video port**. Other than that it should be safe:

In terminal,

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=SVIDEO-1:d"
```

Save and close Gedit.

Then, in Terminal, do

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot & test.

Comment: Great. Please consider accepting/upvoting the answer so it can be useful for other users.

Comment: this increased my boot time by at least 15 seconds too. Thanks